# Not able to upgrade Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, upgrade, dpkg, docker

I'm facing problem with `/usr/bin/dpkg`. I tried not able to figure it out.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  docker.io
The following packages will be upgraded:
  code
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 261729 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing docker.io (1.13.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
Expected a command, got perl -- Check the available commands and options and syntax with 'help'
dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker.io
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly the same but I had a similar error with the same ~ error message. I have to open (`pkexec gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`) and manually remove all entries related to docker. Then latter everything was working. This actually happened twice with docker and with cuda also.